# Angular recursive directive with functions

Tags: angularjs

New to angular and trying to wrap my head around these scopes. I want the functions to be inherited infinetly down my tree. The code below is what I have and it works for the first level, but after that I'm sort of lost. Any ideas?

```
<tree get-branch="GetBranch(parent, $event)" show-menu="ShowMenu(parent)" family="i"></tree> 

$scope.GetBranch = function (parent, $event) {...
$scope.ShowMenu = function(parent) {...

App.directive("tree", function (RecursionHelper) {
return {
    restrict: "E",
    scope: {
        getBranch: "&",
        showMenu: "&",
        family: '='
    },
    template:
        '<a ng-right-click="showMenu({ parent: family })" ng-click="getBranch({parent:family, $event:$event})" >{{ family.Alias }}</a>' +
        '<ul ng-if="family.IsCategory">' +
            '<li ng-repeat="child in family.Children" ng-class="{category: child.IsCategory}">' +
                '<tree get-branch="getBranch({family:family, $event:$event})" show-menu="showMenu({ family: family })" family="child"></tree>' +
            '</li>' +
        '</ul>',
    compile: function (element) {
        return RecursionHelper.compile(element, function (scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller, transcludeFn) {
            // Define your normal link function here.
            // Alternative: instead of passing a function,
            // you can also pass an object with 
            // a 'pre'- and 'post'-link function.
        });
    }
};
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a function to be usable anywhere, or any value to be shared anywhere in your application I think your approach is wrong. This is typically something that should be in a service or a factory. Have a look at https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services

Comment: Made a quick search and: Should I use a service and then add it to my directive scope with link? Or how would I get it in there?

Comment: Yes you should get it with an injection like you use $scope or any angular service. Example, if your service is called 'myFunctions' then just add myFunctions besides $scope